# Overlapping Pointers

Tags: c

I have a case in which I have a `uint64_t*`, a `char*` (6 chars long), and a `uint16_t*` that point to the addresses `x`, `x+2`, and `x` respectively. So if the char* points to "This i" then the `uint16_t*` should point to the value `0` dec, and the `uint64_t*` should point to the value `115, 588, 096, 157, 780` dec.

But when I look at these values I am getting 0 dec for the `uint64_t` I do not understand why this would be. Could someone explain?

Edit (added code):

```
FILE *file = fopen("/Users/Justin/Desktop/test.txt", "rb");
uint64_t *window = malloc(8);
char *buffer = (char*)(window+2);
uint16_t *data = (uint16_t*)window;
uint16_t *read = (uint16_t*)(window+6);

fread(buffer, 6, 1, file);

printf("%p\n", window);
printf("%p\n", buffer);
printf("%p\n", data);
printf("%p\n", read);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
printf("%llu\n", *window);
```

and the output is:

```
0x100105440
0x100105450
0x100105440
0x100105470
This i
0
```

Comment: Are your characters in ASCII or another UTF character set.  For example all ASCII characters have decimal values between 0 and 127; and 588 is outside the range.

Comment: The code is in `c`. Why is the question tagged `c++`?

Comment: So you've printed out pointer values... Are you testing how pointer arithmetic works?

Comment: uint64_t is 8 bytes long, and you allocate a uint64_t pointer to 8 bytes of memory. But then you reference the 3rd element of it. That's out of the defined memory space, so anything could happen. Maybe you intended to move it along by 2 *bytes*? Try casting to char or void before adding.

Comment: The code is printing the pointers, not what they point to... Also you can't just expect uninitialized values to be 0.

Comment: This is all valid c++ code. I didn't see a reason to exclude c++

Comment: C++ is a different language than C. Pick one. (spoiler:) In this case pick C

Comment: `uint64_t *window = malloc(8);` -- is not valid C++ code. Unless you have a function named malloc which returns `uint64_t*`.

Comment: @void_ptr The memory addresses line up as I would expect. I am not referencing any memory outside of the `uint64_t`'s allocated memory

Comment: Also you're getting lucky that the memory is 0 at the start. If your program had been running for a while, or on an OS which doesn't privacy-protect application RAM, that memory could be set to anything. Even if you fix the pointer arithmetic you'll still need to 0-out the first 2 bytes of that memory for it to be safe. And don't forget to malloc 9 bytes to allow the `\0`

Comment: @JDOdle the memory addresses do not line up; they should be 0x100105440 and 0x100105442 for what you're intending. As I said in my first comment, and Dieter said just now, you're incrementing by too much (16 bytes instead of 2 bytes)

Comment: @JDOdle: Why do you say the addresses line up as you would expect? They line up as *I* would expect. But your expectations are completely wrong. Are you sure you are reading them correctly?

Comment: **here be dragons**: `uint16_t *data = (uint16_t*)window;` when window is `uint64_t`: dereferencing data will result in **undefined behavior** due to **strict aliasing** rules.

Comment: c++ tag has been removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting tripped up by pointer math.

As `window` is declared as `uint64_t *`, `window + 2` does not increment the address by two bytes; it increments it by `2 * sizeof(uint64_t)` (that is, sixteen bytes). As a result, the memory you're looking at is uninitialized (and, in fact, lies outside the allocated block).

If you actually want the address to be incremented by two bytes, you'll need to cast the pointer to `char *` *before* adding 2 to it:

```
char *buffer = ((char *) window) + 2;
```

Comment: I was thinking that the mem addresses showing were bit addresses rather than byte addresses. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding what the `+2` does here:

```
uint64_t *window = malloc(8);
char *buffer = (char*)(window+2);
```

It helps to visualize the data that we got back from `malloc`, using `|` to help show 8-byte boundaries:

```
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------
^
window
```

Now, `buffer` doesn't point two *bytes* ahead of `window`. It points two `uint64_t`'s ahead. Or in other words, `((char*)window) + 2 * sizeof(*window)`:

```
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------
^               ^
window          buffer
```

which you then fread into

```
|-------|-------This i--|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------
^               ^
window          buffer
```

If you want to just point two *bytes* ahead, you have to add the 2 to a `char*`:

```
char* buffer = ((char*)window) + 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the pointer math issues that @duskwuff pointed out and @Barry clarified, there is also another issue.  The answer you get will depend on the computer architecture on which this code runs.

On big-endian machines you'll get one answer, on little-endian machines you'll get a different answer.

Oh, and one more thing.   Writing buffer using %s is very dangerous.   If there are no zero bytes in the data read from the file, it will wander through memory until it finds one.

Comment: Or until it page faults, which is probably a better end.

Comment: _Writing buffer using %s is very dangerous_...  Perhaps provide an alternative method to write a buffer in a less dangerous way?

Comment: I took endianess into consideration when posting my question, and the %s was just for a quick confirmation I would not normally do it this way

Comment: OK. I just didn't want anyone seeing this code and thinking it was an acceptable technique.